# Make an exception on AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller with many actions. All should be accessible to certain users only except one action:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class SecretsController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

Even `[Authorize (Roles = null)]` doesn't work. The method attribute will be ignored! How could I get the exception for just one action? Like `AllowAnonymous` allows it but visible to logged in users?

Comment: "Except one action" that you want to be accessible to all *authenticated* users regardless of their role? Or allow anonymous access as well?

Comment: Visible to all users who are logged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `OverrideAuthorization` attribute like I do in the code below :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class SecretsController : Controller
{

    [OverrideAuthorization]
    [Authorize()]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

With `[OverrideAuthorization]` which came with ASP.Net MVC5 you tell your `Index`  action to override/ignore the authorization rules defined at the controller level.

By doing this, all your actions defined in `SecretsController` are visible only to **Admin** role except `Index` action which will be visible only to authenticated user even if they are not in **Admin** role.

Comment: Awesome! I've never known `OverrideAuthorization` exists! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

use the attribute AllowAnonymous

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class SecretsController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Edit**
Since the question was edited *right* after my answer to precisely mention not wanting the anonymous option

> Like AllowAnonymous allows it but visible to logged in users?

The best answer is now CodeNotFound's answer